# Simplify and combine LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm currently working on a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application. I wrote a LINQ statement to retrieve a value from a keyValuePair with a given structure. The value is of type object and can either be true, false or "0".

The keyValuePair contains a `Dictionary<string, object>` and looks something similar to that:

[image]

- Key: "IsFruit" Value: true
- Key: "IsVegetable" Value: false
- Key: "IsMeat" Value: "0"

I want to select the boolean value only. My LINQ query to retrieve the value looks like that:

```
var val = fruitOrVegetable
    .Where(pair => pair.Key == "IsFruit")
    .FirstOrDefault().Value;

bool isFruitAtPosition;
bool.TryParse(val.ToString(), out isFruitAtPosition);
```

Actually my code works fine, it's just, I'm not too happy about it and I'm thinking perhaps there is a way to merge/combine those lines into 1 statement or something.

Do you have some ideas on how to improve my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always make your own extension method for converting object into bool or null.

Such as

```
public static bool? AsBoolOrDefault(this object objectToParse)
{
    return objectToParse is bool ? objectToParse as bool? : null;
}
```

and use it in your query like

```
bool? isFruitAtPosition = fruitOrVegetable.Where(pair => pair.Key == "IsFruit")
                                          .FirstOrDefault().Value.AsBoolOrDefault()
```

And you can use it everywhere not only in queries.

> Off topic

If use access any property or method after use `FirstOrDefaut` and other null able selection methods, you are calling for `NullReferenceException`. I think it is generaly good idea to make a null check.

In C# 6 you can use the Null Conditional Operator.

```
bool? isFruitAtPosition = fruitOrVegetable.Where(pair => pair.Key == "IsFruit")
                                          .FirstOrDefault()?.Value.AsBoolOrDefault()
```

Comment: Just `return (objectToParse as bool?)`

Answer (score 1):

It's a dictionary... you don't need LINQ.

If you only need to know if the position is present, then:

```
bool isFruitAtPosition = fruitOrVegetable.ContainsKey("IsFruit")? fruitOrVegetable["IsFruit"] as bool? ?? false : false;
```

Or, if you do need both variables:

```
var val = fruitOrVegetable.ContainsKey("IsFruit")? fruitOrVegetable["IsFruit"] : new object();
bool isFruitAtPosition = val as bool? ?? false;
```

Feel free to remix this into something more readable depending on your actual code base. If the Dictionary is small, then there wont be much difference between iterating. If it is large or has implicit performance impacts, this will be a crucial approach to use.

Comment: @Fabjan - It cannot be used because `TryGetValue` would be expecting an `out object` instead of `out bool`.

Answer (score 1):

I like this version.

```
var isFruitAtPosition = fruitOrVegetable.Any( p => p.Key == "IsFruit" && (bool)p.Value );
```

Comment: So you suspect that there are more than 1 occurrence of the same key in Dictionary ?

Comment: @Febjan Not at all. I think of the business rule as "This entity is a fruit when its dictionary contains an entry that says it is" and this LINQ is the clearest way I can think of to express that. The fact that it does not depend on a concrete implementation is a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use LINQ as following:

```
var val = fruitOrVegetable.FirstOrDefault(item => item.key == "IsFruit");
```

then you can try to cast to bool.

Just a thought: If the value for Key: "IsMeat" be either  0 or 1 , can you not make it a bool type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice extension method you could use, it is generic and possible to use for other Types then bool/bool?:

```
public class Program
{

 public static void Main()
 {
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>{
        {"test1", true},
        {"test2", 2}
    };

    var result = dict.GetDictionaryItemValueOrDefault<bool?>("test1");
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
 }
}

public static class Extensions{
 public static T GetDictionaryItemValueOrDefault<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, string key){    
    if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var result) || !(result is T))
       return default(T);

    return (T)result;
 }  
}
```